# Почему "мазаный" здесь с одной "н"?

Tags: морфология

> Бумаги пожелтелые, как деньги -- ещё целые, *зацапа**нн**ые*, *маза**н**ые*,
>   крест-накрест *перевяза**нн**ые*.

Почему *маза**н**ые* с одной **н**? Разве это слово не является здесь причастием? *Перевязанные* точно должно быть причастием, потому что есть наречие *крест-накрест* уточняющее его. *Зацапанные*, в любом случае, должно быть с двумя **н**, потому что оно имеет приставку *за*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Мазаный* - отглагольное прилагательное либо причастие без приставки, от глагола несовершенного вида (*мазать*), без зависимых слов.

http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_106:

> ...Но поскольку полные страдательные причастия иногда очень похожи на
>   прилагательные, чтобы избежать ошибок, полезно помнить четыре условия,
>   при которых пишется две буквы Н:
>
> 1)    причастие имеет приставку ( кроме НЕ-), например, ВЫ-СУШЕННЫЕ
>   ГРИБЫ;
>
> 2)    причастие образовалось от глагола совершенного вида, например,
>   РЕШЕННАЯ ЗАДАЧА - от глагола РЕШИТЬ (что сделать? – соверш. вид);
>
> 3)    причастие имеет зависимые слова, например, ВЫСУШЕННЫЕ (где?) В
>   ПЕЧКЕ ГРИБЫ;
>
> 4)    Причастие образовано от глагола с помощью суффиксов –ОВА- или
>   -ЕВА-, например, ВЗВОЛН-ОВА-ННОЕ ЛИЦО.
>
> Если слово не имеет ни одного из этих признаков, то оно пишется с
>   одним Н.

Comment: Еще можно добавить конкретные исключения: прилагательные _стеклянный, оловянный, деревянный_ пишутся с двумя **н**.

Comment: @Aleks G какое отношение данные слова имеют к глаголам? В данном вопросе выясняется разница между причастиями и отглагольными прилагательными. Ваши исключения не относятся ни к одному, ни к другому.

Comment: @Anixx _Если слово не имеет ни одного из этих признаков, то оно пишется с одним Н_ - именно к этому предложению относился мой комментарий

Comment: @AleksG я забыл уточнить, что цитата относится к только к причастиям и похожим на них отглагольным прилагательным. Конечно, существует и множество других слов с двумя Н.

Comment: Пример 3) более нагляден в виде "сушённые в печке грибы". "Высушённые в печке грибы" несёт сразу три признака -- приставку, совершенный вид и зависимое слово.

Comment: @AviGordon [вЫсушенные](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E2%FB%F1%F3%F8%E5%ED%ED%FB%E9&all=x) - ударение на первом слоге

Comment: @J-mster: Indeed. Sorry. It's a copy-paste error. Still --  "Высушенные в печке грибы" несёт сразу три признака. :)

Comment: @AviGordon: не говоря о том, что *высушенные* происходит от *высушить*--глагола совершенного вида.

Comment: @Graduate: Indeed. Я, как частенько бывает, не приметил слона. :)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у этого слова нет приставки. Так со многими прилагательными. Например стриженый и постриженный, кипячёный и вскипячённый.